Custom Mapbox style not appearing
I am trying to use a custom Mapbox style as my basemap with R and the mapdeck package as shown on the mapdeck site but I can't get it to work. My data layers appear but no map appears in either the R Studio viewer or in a browser window. I have a Mapbox token and my code works when I use one of the standard Mapbox style templates. Am I overlooking something?
Here's the code I am using (on a Mac, in R Studio, private data replaced with {}):
library(mapdeck)

# load csv data ----------
# {my_data}

# load Mapbox token ----------
key <- "{my_token}"

# mapdeck process to plot the data ----------
mapdeck(token = key, style = "mapbox://styles/{my_user_name}/{my_styleID}", pitch = 70) %>% 
  add_arc(
    data = sites
    , layer_id = "arc_layer"
    , origin = c("site_lon", "site_lat")
    , destination = c("lab_lon", "lab_lat")
    , stroke_from = "site"
    , stroke_to = "lab"
  ) %>%
  add_scatterplot(
    data = labs_active
    , layer_id = "scatter"
    , lon = "lon"
    , lat = "lat"
    , radius = 120
    , fill_colour = "status"
  )

I've tried different browsers but none have made a difference.
Here are some of the browser console messages I get (in Safari):

Error: layers[39].filter[3][1][0]: Unknown expression "pitch". If you wanted a literal array, use ["literal", [...]].
message: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.familiesBySource[this.source]')"
constructor: function()
_classRegistryKey: "Error"
arguments: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.
caller: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context
[Warning] WebGL: non-portable extension enabled: WEBGL_polygon_mode


Does it work if you use one of the provided styles: mapdeck(style = mapdeck_style('dark')) ?

@tospig Yes, the provided styles work.

so is the issue is with this line specifically: mapdeck(token = key, style = "mapbox://styles/{my_user_name}/{my_styleID}") ? Can you make your style public and put the full URL here?

@tospig Yes, I think the issue is with that line. Maybe this is an issue with Mapbox or Deckgl? Do the console messages that I am getting mean anything? For now, I was hoping not to make my style public.

I don't recognise those errors. If you remove the add_() calls, do you still get those errors? Is there another public style you can use to test this?

@tospig Thanks, I tried a bunch of different things: another public style worked but mine still didn't, even if I made mine public. I still got errors after removing the add() calls. I tweaked various Mapbox style settings and data sources with no benefit. Finally, what worked was creating my own Mapbox map style completely from scratch. My first attempt, the one that wasn't working, was a style based off of one of Mapbox's "classic templates" (Monochrome) where I had tweaked colors. I will note this as an answer to my original post.

What worked was creating my own Mapbox map style completely from scratch, then replacing the old style link with my new style link:
mapdeck(token = key, style = "mapbox://styles/{my_user_name}/{my_NEW_styleID}")

My original Mapbox style was a style based on one of Mapbox's built-in style templates (see my responses to @tospig in the comments). I am still not sure why that didn't work.
